# Remove elements from one array if present in another array, keep duplicates - NumPy / Python

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop, unique

I have two arrays `A` (len of 3.8million)  and `B` (len of 20k).
For the minimal example, lets take this case:

```
A = np.array([1,1,2,3,3,3,4,5,6,7,8,8])
B = np.array([1,2,8])
```

Now I want the resulting array to be:

```
C = np.array([3,3,3,4,5,6,7])
```

**i.e. if any value in `B` is found in `A`, remove it from `A`, if not keep it.**

I would like to know if there is **any way to do it without a `for` loop** because it is a lengthy array and so it takes long time to loop.

Comment: . Is `B` sorted?

Comment: @Divakar: nope, but I can sort it if needed, it's not a problem

Comment: Wouldn't `numpy.setdiff1d` do exactly what you need?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

#### Using `searchsorted`

With sorted `B`, we can use [`searchsorted`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) -

```
A[B[np.searchsorted(B,A)] !=  A]
```

From the linked docs, `searchsorted(a,v)` find the indices into a sorted array `a` such that, if the corresponding elements in `v` were inserted before the indices, the order of a would be preserved. So, let's say `idx = searchsorted(B,A)` and we index into `B` with those : `B[idx]`, we will get a mapped version of `B` corresponding to every element in `A`. Thus, comparing this mapped version against `A` would tell us for every element in `A` if there's a match in `B` or not. Finally, index into `A` to select the non-matching ones.

**Generic case (`B` is not sorted) :**

If `B` is not already sorted as is the pre-requisite, sort it and then use the proposed method.

Alternatively, we can use `sorter` argument with `searchsorted` -

```
sidx = B.argsort()
out = A[B[sidx[np.searchsorted(B,A,sorter=sidx)]] != A]
```

**More generic case (`A`  has values higher than ones in `B`) :**

```
sidx = B.argsort()
idx = np.searchsorted(B,A,sorter=sidx)
idx[idx==len(B)] = 0
out = A[B[sidx[idx]] != A]
```

---

#### Using `in1d/isin`

We can also use [`np.in1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html), which is pretty straight-forward (the linked docs should help clarify) as it looks for any match in  `B` for every element in `A` and then we can use boolean-indexing with an inverted mask to look for non-matching ones -

```
A[~np.in1d(A,B)]
```

Same with `isin` -

```
A[~np.isin(A,B)]
```

With `invert` flag -

```
A[np.in1d(A,B,invert=True)]

A[np.isin(A,B,invert=True)]
```

This solves for a generic when `B` is not necessarily sorted.

Comment: Can I get more information as to how the two methods work ?

Comment: using `timeit`, it seems the 1st method is about 2 times faster

Comment: @ThePredator Added comments.

Comment: This is a great and to the point answer, but this won't work directly if the range of values in A is larger than in B (that is - if there are larger values in A that are not in B). I'll add a complementary answer for future reference

Comment: @vmg Good point! Edited solution to handle those cases too.

Answer (score 5):

I am not very familiar with numpy, but how about using sets:

```
C = set(A.flat) - set(B.flat)
```

EDIT : from comments, sets cannot have duplicates values.

So another solution would be to use a lambda expression :

```
C = np.array(list(filter(lambda x: x not in B, A)))
```

Comment: Sets cannot include duplicate values.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to [Divakar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52417967/2861681) above -

if the original array A has a wider range than B, that will give you an 'index out of bounds' error. See:

```
A = np.array([1,1,2,3,3,3,4,5,6,7,8,8,10,12,14])
B = np.array([1,2,8])

A[B[np.searchsorted(B,A)] !=  A]
>> IndexError: index 3 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 3
```

This will happen because `np.searchsorted` will assign index 3 (one-past-the-last in B) as the appropriate position for inserting in B the elements 10, 12 and 14 from A, in this example. Thus you get an IndexError in `B[np.searchsorted(B,A)]`.

To circumvent that, a possible approach is:

```
def subset_sorted_array(A,B):
    Aa = A[np.where(A <= np.max(B))]
    Bb = (B[np.searchsorted(B,Aa)] !=  Aa)
    Bb = np.pad(Bb,(0,A.shape[0]-Aa.shape[0]), method='constant', constant_values=True)
    return A[Bb]
```

Which works as follows:

```
# Take only the elements in A that would be inserted in B
Aa = A[np.where(A <= np.max(B))]

# Pad the resulting filter with 'Trues' - I split this in two operations for
# easier reading
Bb = (B[np.searchsorted(B,Aa)] !=  Aa)
Bb = np.pad(Bb,(0,A.shape[0]-Aa.shape[0]),  method='constant', constant_values=True)

# Then you can filter A by Bb
A[Bb]
# For the input arrays above:
>> array([ 3,  3,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7, 10, 12, 14])
```

Notice this will also work between arrays of strings and other types (for all types for which the comparison `<=` operator is defined).