# Python IndexError: index 612472 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 612472

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, indexoutofboundsexception

Apologies in advance python is not my strong point. I am trying to use the solution found in:

[Remove elements from one array if present in another array, keep duplicates - NumPy / Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52417929/remove-elements-from-one-array-if-present-in-another-array-keep-duplicates-nu)

That is I have a very large one dimensional array shaped (21684142,) and I want to remove any elements from this array that appear in a second array shaped (612472,). The solution above looks to suit this perfectly however when I run the code below:

```
friendsArray = np.array(friendsMap)
friendsArray.sort()
alreadyArray = np.array(alreadyMap)
alreadyArray.sort()
finalarray  = friendsArray[alreadyArray[np.searchsorted(alreadyArray,friendsArray)] !=  friendsArray]
```

This results in the error below:

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-35-c0c68109f51f> in <module>
  4 alreadyArray.sort()
  5 
  ----> 6 finalarray  = friendsArray[alreadyArray[np.searchsorted(alreadyArray,friendsArray)] !=  
  friendsArray]

  IndexError: index 612472 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 612472
```

Any ideas or pointers of where to go next? I tried to reshape the array without success. Any help is much appreciated.

Neil.

Comment: If the axis has size 612472 the highest valid index is 612471, i.e. one less.

Comment: Thanks very much mkriger1 so I should investigate increasing the axis of the smaller array?

Comment: I have resized the second array using alreadyArray.resize(21684142,) but I'm afraid I still get the same error message with the figure 21684142 in place of 612472.

Comment: You can resize as much as you want. As long as you don’t calculate the index correctly this will not solve any problem. For any array with size N the valid indices are 0 to N–1.

Comment: Thanks I will look into this